# Trouble displaying stl file in SceneKit with macOS

Tags: macos, scenekit

i have a binary stl file, it can display in ios scenekit,  but can't display in macOs with same code . when i load the file,  some time app crash, some time it display wrong thing

macOs 10.14.6

---

```
- (SCNNode *)loadBinarySTLWithData:(NSData *)data{

NSMutableData *vertices = [NSMutableData data];
NSMutableData *normals = [NSMutableData data];
NSMutableData *elements = [NSMutableData data];
if (data.length % 50 != 0){
    return nil;
}
NSInteger allCount = data.length/50;
for (int i = 0; i < allCount; i ++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j ++){
        [normals appendData:[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i * 50, 12)]];
        [vertices appendData:[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i * 50 + j*12, 12)]];
    }
    int element[3] = {(int)i * 3,(int)i*3 + 1,(int)i*3 + 2};
    [elements appendBytes:&element[0] length:sizeof(element)];
}
SCNGeometrySource *verticesSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:vertices semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex vectorCount:allCount*3 floatComponents:YES componentsPerVector:3 bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float) dataOffset:0 dataStride:sizeof(SCNVector3)];
SCNGeometrySource *normalsSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:normals semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal vectorCount:allCount*3 floatComponents:YES componentsPerVector:3 bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float) dataOffset:0 dataStride:sizeof(SCNVector3)];
SCNGeometryElement *geoMetryElement = [SCNGeometryElement geometryElementWithData:elements primitiveType:SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeTriangles primitiveCount:allCount bytesPerIndex:sizeof(int)];
SCNGeometry *geometry = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:@[verticesSource,normalsSource] elements:@[geoMetryElement]];
geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
geometry.firstMaterial.doubleSided = YES;
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:geometry];
return node;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCNVector3` has different declarations on iOS and macOS:

```c
// iOS
typedef struct SCNVector3 {
    float x, y, z;
} SCNVector3;
```

```c
// macOS
typedef struct SCNVector3 {
    CGFloat x, y, z;
} SCNVector3;
```

And `CGFloat` is `double` when compiling for 64bits.
This means `sizeof(SCNVector3)` is not the correct stride on macOS. You should use `3 * sizeof(float)` instead.